# Store load before main Application ViewPort load

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm running into a problem I have a store that I need to load before my Applications ViewPort is called. But when I have

```
autoCreateViewPort : true
```

My store is load after the ViewPort which won't work. I need to load the current user Model or Store before my applications ViewPort is rendered. Since my ViewPort loads panels the uses data from the Store. Any ideas on show I can make sure the store loads before the application ViewPort is created and displayed?

Comment: An additional solution to this is to have a server side script rendering a javascript with the user data. On the most simple form, something like this in php: echo "var usertype = 'admin';".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can insert a `Ext.onReady` block and within that

- create the store
- create a function and build your `Ext.application` within that function
- attach a listener to the store's `load` event, with the option `{ single: true }` and the function above as the callback

I never tested it but that should work.

Another (and recommend) option is to use your own viewport and load the store within that. There you can track the load operation the same way.